# Numerical value from Simple HTML Dom Parser treated as text

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to pull information from a webpage.  One of the values that I retrieve is a number.  Here's how I retrieve the value:

```
$num = $html->find('a[id=reviews_link] span');
```

Then if I want to print the number(s):

```
foreach($num as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

This works properly and prints the correct number(s) from the original page.  However, if I want to use the number in a logical statement, it does not work.  So for example if there is a single number returned and its value is 20, when I do this:

```
foreach($num as $val){
    if($val > 15){
        echo $val." is greater than 15";
    }
}
```

The if statement is not triggered and nothing prints.  The same happens if I add quotes around the variable (`"$val"`).  I have also tried using various PHP functions like `intval` or `float` but that doesn't change anything.

How can I get this variable to be treated as a numerical value?

When I `print_r($val)` there is a super long `simple_html_dom_node Object` that prints, it appears to contain a bunch of arrays.

Comment: when you say that `intval` doesn't work, are you actually using `intval` on `$val`? Because that is what you should do. Like `if(intval($val) > 15){...`

Comment: Yes, same result when I do `if(intval($val) > 15)`.  Thanks for suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$val` is actually a `simple_html_dom_node` object, and `echo $val;` only works as this class implements the magic `__toString()` method. This only works in certain situations though, but especially *not* in comparisons.

Here you need to refer to actual object properties, here probably

```
if ($val->outertext > 15)
```

or

```
if ($val->plaintext > 15)
```

See also the "Magic Attributes" tab under http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access

Comment: Actually, it looks like best practice is to include `intval`, so this would work best: `if (intval($val->plaintext) > 15)`

Answer (score 1):

Because `$num` is an array of Dom objects and each `$val` is a dom object, not a number. It prints as a number because of its `__tostring()` method, but that does not convert it to an integer.

I believe this will work:

```
foreach($num as $val){
    if($val->value > 15){ // or $val->attributeName for whatever attribute contains the value
        echo $val." is greater than 15";
    }
}
```

Comment: nope, won't work here as this is not using the PHP DOM extension but http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ , so the attribute names are different ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe, I was referencing attribute access as described at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_access